# Wouldst thou like or likest?

Tags: archaicisms, auxiliary-verbs, conjugation, will-future

The phrase "wouldst thou like" seems more appropriate to me, for the following reason:

As far as I know, "thou wilt like" is correct, and "thou wilt likest" is not, because the verb "like" is infinitive, here, due to the presence of the auxiliary verb "will". Therefore, "thou wouldst like" is correct, for the same reason. I don't see why rearranging the phrase into interrogative form should change the conjugation of the verb "like", but English is strange, and that's why I ask: Would it be correct to assume that the proper conjugation of verbs for the phrase I'm looking for is "wouldst thou like"?

Comment: English is not **that** strange. You only need one -_st_ to mark the 2nd person present. You got that on _wouldst_ already. Parallel in modern English would be *_Does he likes it?_, because _-s_ marks 3rd person present still, even though _-st_ no longer marks 2nd.

Comment: @JohnLawler Why that's just what I needed to know, thank you. If you post that as an answer, I will mark it as accepted. I liked the parallel to modern English, as it makes it much clearer.

Comment: I'd avoid 'thou wiltest ....'